# How to implement an FIR filter in C to process one sample at a time

Tags: filter, signal-processing, avr

The following code is for the implementation of a real-time FIR filter was taken from a DSP textbook. However, I would like to process one sample at a time, produce the corresponding output then move on to the next sample in real-time. Should I append each new sample to the input array or is there another way to do this?

```
        /*====================================================
      Dig_FIR_Filt_RT() - filters input array using FIR
      coefs (uses real-time code)
      Prototype: void Dig_FIR_Filt_RT(int *X,int *Y,
      double *M,double *C,int numb_coefs,int N);
      Return: error value.
      Arguments: X - ptr to input array
      Y - ptr to output array
      M - ptr to memory array
      C - ptr to coefs array
      numb_coefs - number of coefficients
      N - number of values in array
      ====================================================*/
      void Dig_FIR_Filt_RT(int *X,int *Y,double *M,double *C
      ,int numb_coefs,int N)
      { int *x,*y, /* ptrs to in/out arrays */
          i,j; /* loop counters */
          double *c,*m1,*m2, /* ptrs to coef/memory array */
          o; /* output value */
          /* Make copies of input and output pointers */
          x = X;
          y = Y;
          /* Start loop for number of data values */
          for(i = 0; i < N ;i++)
          { /* Make copy of pointers and start loop */
          M[numb_coefs-1] = *x++;
          c = C;
          m1 = m2 = M;
          o = *m1++ * *c++;
          /* Use convolution method for computation */
          for(j = 1; j < numb_coefs ;j++)
          { *m2++ = *m1;
          o += *m1++ * *c++;
          }
          /* Multiply by gain, convert to int and store */
          o *= *c;
          *y++ = (int)ceil(o-0.5);
          }
      }
```

Comment: It will be easier to help you if you supply more info/code regarding what you tried, and what didn't work.

Comment: As I wrote in a comment to my answer, noise can be the result of many things. But first, you use `k` as index without initializing it. That's a first bug you need to fix. Other than than, see my other comment.

Comment: I will attempt this today

Comment: No luck with the previous approach @ItamarKatz, could you have a look at the updated code?

Answer (score 0):

Usually it's a good practice to make your algorithm independent of the buffer size (= the number of new samples you read each time). Your algorithm should take care of keeping past samples it may need, and be able to handle any number of input samples. In the case of FIR filter, it means you must accumulate `N` samples before you can output the 1st filtered sample, for a filter of order `N`. If you wrote your filter with this in mind, you can then just call it with a single input sample, or buffer of size 1. In pseudo-code:

1. Get `m` new samples from the audio device/analog input/etc.
2. copy all new samples to an array the algorithm holds.
3. Apply the FIR filter to all samples from `last new sample` to newest sample.
4. Update `last new sample` to point to the newest sample filtered.

Comment: If you know you only need one sample at once, you can make the buffer circular. That is both easy to implement and more efficient than shifting up the buffer with each new sample.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Itamar. I figured as much at a high level but the technical implementation is what is problematic. I convolve each sample and return the result to be output via pwm but the result is just noise.

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean how exactly would I modify my code to accomplish this?

Comment: There could be a lot of reasons for getting noise in the output. You need to debug your code and your hardware (input, microcontroller, output). Ideally, feed the input with a known signal (zero, DC, sine wave, etc.), and write down the output before the PWM, make sure it makes sense. Look at the output voltage using an oscilloscope. That's the starting point.